# How to read strings as many times as the entered number is equal to?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm having trouble rewriting my code.

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char pole[100];
int i = 0;
char *token;
char *space = " \r\n";
while(fgets(pole, 100, stdin)){
    int j = 0;
    token = strtok(pole, space);
    while (token != NULL){
        if (strlen(token) > 0){
            j++;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
    } 
    if (strcmp(pole, "x") == 0 || strcmp(pole , "x\n") == 0){
       break;
    }
    i += j; 
}
for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){
    printf("Word %d: \n", x);
}
return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Hello I am human
Programming
Apple moon
x
```

Output:

```
Word 0: 
Word 1: 
Word 2: 
Word 3: 
Word 4: 
Word 5: 
Word 6:
```

But I want to write the number of strings at the beginning then the strings like this (without "x"):

```
3
Hello I am human
Programming
Apple moon
```

and get this

```
Word 0: 
Word 1: 
Word 2: 
Word 3: 
Word 4: 
Word 5: 
Word 6:
```

I've tried this to solve this problem, but it doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char pole[100];
int i = 0;
int cislo;
int cislo2 = 0;
char *token;
char *space = " \r\n";
scanf("%d", &cislo);
while (cislo2 < cislo){
    while(fgets(pole, 100, stdin)){
        int j = 0;
        token = strtok(pole, space);
        while (token != NULL){
            if (strlen(token) > 0){
                j++;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, space);
        } 
        }
        i += j;
        break; 
}
for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){
    printf("Word %d: \n", x);
}
return 0;
}
```

I have no idea how to improve my program to get what I want. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things:

1. You need to use`while (cislo2 <= cislo)` otherwise you'll be off by one.
2. Place `i += j` inside the inner while loop.
3. Why use a while loop if you break out anyway (replace the second while loop with an if)
4. Count up `cislo2`, otherwise you got yourself an infinite loop

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char pole[100];
    int i = 0;
    int cislo;
    int cislo2 = 0;
    char *token;
    char *space = " \r\n";
    scanf("%d", &cislo);
    while (cislo2 <= cislo){
        if (fgets(pole, 100, stdin)){
            int j = 0;
            token = strtok(pole, space);
            while (token != NULL){
                if (strlen(token) > 0){
                    j++;
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, space);
            } 
            i += j;
        }
        cislo2++;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){
        printf("Word %d: \n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```